# Can a Mavic Freewheel Body (HG11 B9) fit into a 28"Mavic Ksyrium Elite Wheel (that already has a Shimano freehub)?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, conversion, freehub, campagnolo

I have a Campagnolo Chorus groupset and wanted to switch my rear wheel to a newer one.

I found a Mavic Ksyrium Elite rear wheel (older series) that had a Shimano freehub in it.

[image]

I have a Mavic Campagnolo freehub body (HG11 B9).

[image]

In this case, would I be able to use the Shimano freehub and the Campagnolo freehub interchangeably (of course with a corresponding cassette). Would it fit the Mavic Ksyrium Elite wheel hub?

Looking forward to any suggestions

Best

Comment: I knew it was hard finding parts for Mavic/Campagnolo but I didn't know it would be even harder finding an answer for them.

Answer (score 2):

The question is hard to answer without knowing the exact version of the wheel.

Mavic has a good technical manual website, that can help to check compatibilities:
https://technicalmanual.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data/mavic_tech.php

From what I could see, most of the Ksyrium Elite have Campagnolo and Shimano freehub bodies among the parts (Campagnolo freehubs are called "EDxx", Shimano "MDxx"), so provided that you have matching freehub bodies and hubs, you can use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the wheel interface on the Campagnolo freehub matches the wheel. Mavic updated the interfaces on their road wheels from FTSL to ID360. The two interfaces are not the compatible.

- FTSL uses pawls
- ID360 uses a ratchet drive

Have a look at the end of the freehubs where they attach to the wheel. If they look the same you can use the Campagnolo freehub interchangeably.